# How to change the color of scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I want to change the color of the scroll bar.For creating the scroll bar I used the given code.
javascript is

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();


    $('#body').bind(
    'jsp-scroll-y',
    function (event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
        console.log('#pane1 Handle jsp-scroll-y', this,
                        'scrollPositionY=', scrollPositionY,
                        'isAtTop=', isAtTop,
                        'isAtBottom=', isAtBottom);
    }
);
```

css is

```
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But here I cannot change the color of the scroll bar.How can I change the color?
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KVyAG/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two elements are basically the scroll bar and drag handler.

```
.jspTrack {
    background: lightgray !important;
}

.jspDrag {
    background: gray !important;
}
```

Edit: really making sure the colors get applied.

Comment: Either make sure that these styles are applied after the default jScrollPane styles or increase the [css selector specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Updated my answer with the more specific selectors.

Comment: Maybe you have to give us more insights in how you include the jsp and your own styles (order), else I'd recommend the same as Pasha and use the `!important` statement. If that still does not work I would believe that jScrollPane doesn't even get applied and you still have the default browser scroll bar styles...

Comment: So this is exactly the same as on your page? because you're missing three files there for jScrollPane to work, even the plugin code itself.

Comment: i Got it yar.. Thank you for your help.Actually its a conflict problem.I have two jquery file

Answer (score 2):

You can stylize drag element `.jspDrag`:

```
.jspDrag {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

and the scollbar `.jspVerticalBar` itself:

```
.jspVerticalBar {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

**UPD**
Working example http://jsfiddle.net/KVyAG/2/

Comment: check that your styles defined after jScrollPane styles

Comment: yep..I declared it after jScrollPane styles..have you any example

Comment: try to use `!important` keyword if that works that means that rules works fine and you should to fix selectors.

Comment: If it's all bout selectors you should to look at console which rule overwrites them, then make fixes to your selectors and remove important keyword.

Comment: Do you've link some additional css file for you jsp?

Comment: i just add only this <style type="text/css">
 
.scroll-pane
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 overflow: auto;
}
.scroll-pane .jspTrack {
    background: lightgray !important;
}

.scroll-pane .jspDrag {
    background: gray !important;
}
</style>

Comment: remove `.scoll-pane` selector for `.jspDrag` and `.jspTrack`

Comment: removed.. I can set the width and height of the scroll bar.. So it is working right?

Comment: You should be able to tell us if it's working yourself ;). Do the colors get applied?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KVyAG/2/ add external resources like jquery mousewheel and jscrollpane css

Comment: Hey! Agent1 WTF!? My answer was correct and written earlier and has working example.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.
For particular **class or id** you can just write name of **class or id** instead of **BODY**

```
 <style type="text/css">
    BODY{
    scrollbar-face-color:#DFFFBF;
    scrollbar-shadow-color:green;
    }
    </style>
```

You can also use following property:

- 1) scrollbar-3dlight-color 2) scrollbar-arrow-color 3)
  scrollbar-base-color 4) scrollbar-darkshadow-color 5)
  scrollbar-face-color 6) scrollbar-highlight-color 7)
  scrollbar-shadow-color 8) scrollbar-track-color

Comment: This only works in IE and Opera, in Opera only for body selector. http://www.css4you.de/scrollbar-face-color.html (counts for all of those properties)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.scroll-pane
 {
 width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color:#000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can change color of scrollbar using javascript also. There are various components in scroll bar like base color, face color, arrow color etc that changes color of various parts of scroll bar. The following lines might help you.

```
document.body.style.scrollbarBaseColor = "colorname";
document.body.style.scrollbarArrowColor = "colorname";
document.body.style.scrollbarTrackColor = "colorname";
```

Apart from the above styles, you will have scrollbarShadowColor, scrollbarHighlightColor, scrollbar3dlightColor,scrollbarDarkshadowColor etc. So, choose your component of scroll bar and change the color of it.